# No data for table with 2 foreign keys to one table EF 6

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

ASP.NET. EF 6.0.2, MVC 5.1.1.
I have a table with 2 foreign keys to the same table.

```
public class order
{
public int orderID {get;set;}
public int deliveryplaceID {get;set;}
public int invoiceplaceID {get;set;}

public virtual Place Deliveryplace {get;set;}
public virtual Place Invoiceplace {get;set;}
}
```

Saving of the object works fine, and the deliverplaceID and invoiceplaceID in the database-table were filled.
Now, when I try to show the data:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
var orderdata = db.order.Include(d => d.Deliveryplace).Include(i => i.Invoiceplace);
return View(orderdata.ToList());
}
```

In the view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Deliveryplace.Zip)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Invoiceplace.Zip)
```

It does not show any data for this two fields. Other fields are shown, also other fields of other foreign tables.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add the entity mapping configuration code to the question?

Comment: What is the "entity mapping configuration" and where I have to find it?

Comment: Hmm...perhaps this is the mistake? Does I have to do some code in OnModelCreating? modelBuilder.Entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Thanks for your tip JC. You put me on the right way.

Solution was
1) Define the foreignkey in order table

```
public class order
{
public int orderID {get;set;}
public int deliveryplaceID {get;set;}
public int invoiceplaceID {get;set;}

[ForeignKey("deliveryplaceID")]
public virtual Place Deliveryplace {get;set;}
[ForeignKey("invoiceplaceID")]
public virtual Place Invoiceplace {get;set;}
}
```

2) Define in modelContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
modelBuilder.Entity<order>()
.HasRequired(c => c.Deliveryplace)
.WithMany()
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<order>()
.HasRequired(c => c.Invoiceplace)
.WithMany()
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it working. You can also specify those foreign keys using the Fluent API instead of using property attributes. Functionally equivalent, but I like to keep my POCOs clean.